# How can I make my java application trust connection using a domain (self) signed certificate?

Tags: tls, windows, certificate-authority, java, active-directory

We have a windows AD domain with servers and clients. The domain also has a Windows Certificate Authority (AD CS). The CA is trusted in the domain by publishing it's public key in the local certificate store for all machines.

We  have a website that uses a local address (`https://mysite.corp.net`) that uses a domain signed certificate. Most clients on the Windows Machines trust the connection, since it is signed by the CA that is trusted by Windows.

Now I have a java client application, that doesn't trust the domain signed certificate, and thus refuses to connect.

**How do i tell the java application to trust the certificate for this site, or better, to trust the CA?**

- I can't 'overrule' or 'ignore' the certificates.
- I need to make sure that the certificates are up-to-date, so that a revoked certificate (or even CA) will not be trusted.

Comment: Java has its own key store and does not use the central windows trust store. Thus you need to add the CA certificate to the java key store. See for example [Adding a Certificate to the Java CA Certificates Store](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java-add-certificate-ca-store). Apart from that you cannot revoke a CA, only distrust it in which case it needs to be removed from all trust stores.

Comment: this might be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate

Answer (score 2):

The comment from Steffen above should be the listed answer, so i'm adding it here:

> Java has its own key store and does not use the central windows trust store. Thus you need to add the CA certificate to the java key store. See for example [Adding a Certificate to the Java CA Certificates Store](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java-add-certificate-ca-store). Apart from that you cannot revoke a CA, only distrust it in which case it needs to be removed from all trust stores.